# Как Юнити определяет какие материалы куда накладывать?

Tags: unity3d

Не совсем уверен, что заголовок поставлен корректно, да и сам вопрос может показаться Вам  глупым, но в Юнити 3д я еще новичок. Тем не менее попробую объяснить суть.

Я скачал с Asset Store префабы машинок и вот одна из них:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня вопрос к списку материалов, которые на ней висят. Если я меняю 0й елемент, то изменения применяются на саму машинку, если 1й, то на стекла, если 2й, то на фары, в независимости от того, какой материал выбрать. Как Юнити определяет, что 0й материал это поверхность, 1й стекла, а 2й фары?

UPD: ассет: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/vehicles/land/low-poly-cars-101798

Comment: А там нода c машинкой не раскрывается в ноды с этими кусками?

Comment: Никак не определяет. Unity не ванга.

Comment: ссылка на материал...

Comment: @user7860670 в объекте еще лежат колеса, а так корпус цельный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все материалы импортируется из модели fbx или прочих 3D форматах, например если назначить материал прозрачности на 3D модели скажем в Blender3D, то Unity будет видеть какой шейдер применялся из Blender, и т.д

Comment: А как мне этим управлять из Юнити?

Comment: 1. Найдите модель не префаб
2. Щёлкните на модель и в инспекторе перейдите в кладку Materials, там же будет экспорт материала и текстур, смотрите на скриншоте https://yadi.sk/i/ollLUnWcvAPbdg

Comment: Спасибо огромное